# ClassNotFoundException Tomcat 7 Server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, classnotfoundexception

I'm getting issues when I try to load something on my Tomcat 7 Server via Eclipse.
I already downloaded an example and tried that one, but in my browser it only shows me that the resource is not available.

```js
Aug 08, 2018 2:23:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFORMATION: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\IFOR\WIN\BIN;C:\IFOR\WIN\BIN\EN_US;C:\TwinCAT\Common32;C:\TwinCAT\Common64;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Users\stn\apache-ant-1.10.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse neon RC3\eclipse;;.
Aug 08, 2018 2:23:51 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:0001' did not find a matching property.
Aug 08, 2018 2:23:51 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:primefaces-test-master' did not find a matching property.
Aug 08, 2018 2:23:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 08, 2018 2:23:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 08, 2018 2:23:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMATION: Initialization processed in 421 ms
Aug 08, 2018 2:23:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting service Catalina
Aug 08, 2018 2:23:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Aug 08, 2018 2:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SCHWERWIEGEND: Error configuring application listener of class ${jsf-listener}
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${jsf-listener}
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Aug 08, 2018 2:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SCHWERWIEGEND: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Aug 08, 2018 2:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: Error listenerStart
Aug 08, 2018 2:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: Context [/primefaces-test] startup failed due to previous errors
Aug 08, 2018 2:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMATION: Marking servlet Push Servlet as unavailable
Aug 08, 2018 2:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet /0001 threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2918)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Aug 08, 2018 2:23:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 08, 2018 2:23:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 08, 2018 2:23:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMATION: Server startup in 2014 ms
```

This is what i got when i run the example on my server. I cant fix the ClassNotFoundException. Does anyone got an idea?

Also it says 2 lines above the second ClassNotFoundException, "SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet /0001 threw load() exception" but /0001 is another Project in the same workspace.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to compile your code cause file (.class) does not generate

Answer (score 0):

Having that $-thingy verbatim with the ClassNotFoundException suggests the conjecture, that ${jsf-listener} is a non-resolved placeholder expression, so that this class is not found. So "jsf-listener" might be missing from some configuration. It is just a conjecture though.

Error configuring application listener of class ${jsf-listener}
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${jsf-listener}

Answer (score 0):

Your artifact for Tomcat  not containing "org.atmosphere" library. Check the way how you build WAR file. In case of Maven you need to add library as compiled dependency.